# Pandas: Automate multiple time series' from a list of events

Tags: python, pandas, loops, time-series, data-visualization

I have a large CSV dataset that includes a `DatetimeIndex` index and two columns of numerical data (`float64`).

I can define a time range and plot my data successfully.

I also have a CSV file that contains lists of "events" that includes the time of the event. There are 100+ events.

I want to be able to iterate through the list of events and plot a time series for every event +/- 12 hours from the event time.
I am relatively new to loops and haven't been able to find any similar topics on here.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/clove/Documents/Tide_data_repo/parsed.csv',parse_dates=['Date_Time'],index_col= ['Date_Time'])
df.Verified = pd.to_numeric(df.Verified, errors='coerce')
df.dropna(axis='index',how='any',inplace=True)

df.info()
df1 = df.loc['2018-05-01':'2018-05-06']


fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
df1.plot(ax=axs)
```

Comment: Will you please post a sample of your dataframe in the question?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Furthermore you can consider to plot it with [plotly](https://plotly.com/) in order to avoid loops

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have created a new thread with an improved format here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963722/how-can-i-automate-the-plotting-of-multiple-chunks-of-data-from-a-very-large-t/70964557#70964557