# How can I automate the plotting of multiple 'chunks' of data from a very large time-series using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, time-series

My goal is to be able to produce a time-series plot for every *event* in 'event.csv' from a large time-series dataset called 'parsed.csv'.

I am able to successfully plot a single event by manually defining the desired time range for an event with a +/- 12 hour buffer as desired.  There are hundreds of events, making automation of some sort necessary.  I am very new to loops/automation and have been extremely stuck.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df_event = pd.read_csv('event.csv',parse_dates['Date_Time'],index_col= ['Date_Time'])
df = pd.read_csv('parsed.csv',parse_dates=['Date_Time'],index_col= ['Date_Time'])

df.Verified = pd.to_numeric(df.Verified, errors='coerce')          #forces columns to float64 dtype
df.dropna(axis='index',how='any',inplace=True)                     #fixes any null values



df = df.loc['2018-05-01':'2018-05-06']                            #can manually define event using this


fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))                          #define axis, and plots
df.plot(ax=axs)



Sample of my large time-series csv dataset:

                        Predicted  Verified
Date_Time                               
2010-01-01 00:00:00      5.161      5.56
2010-01-01 00:06:00      5.187      5.57
2010-01-01 00:12:00      5.208      5.56
2010-01-01 00:18:00      5.222      5.55
2010-01-01 00:24:00      5.230      5.53
                       ...       ...
2020-12-31 23:30:00      3.342      3.81
2020-12-31 23:36:00      3.447      3.92
2020-12-31 23:42:00      3.549      4.03
2020-12-31 23:48:00      3.646      4.14
2020-12-31 23:54:00      3.739      4.24



Event.csv sample:

                        Verified
Date_Time                               
2010-01-06 12:05:00      5.161      
2010-03-13 02:06:00      5.187      
2010-07-24 06:13:00      5.208
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to make a fun interactive plot with Bokeh.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, ColumnDataSource, save
from bokeh.models import WheelZoomTool
from bokeh.models import PanTool
from bokeh.models import ResetTool
from bokeh.models import SaveTool
from bokeh.models import BoxZoomTool
from bokeh.models import CrosshairTool
from bokeh.models import HoverTool


df_dict = {'Date_Time': {0: '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
  1: '2010-01-01 00:06:00',
  2: '2010-01-01 00:12:00',
  3: '2010-01-01 00:18:00',
  4: '2010-01-01 00:24:00',
  5: '2020-12-31 23:30:00',
  6: '2020-12-31 23:36:00',
  7: '2020-12-31 23:42:00',
  8: '2020-12-31 23:48:00',
  9: '2020-12-31 23:54:00'},
 'Predicted': {0: 5.161,
  1: 5.187,
  2: 5.208,
  3: 5.222,
  4: 5.23,
  5: 3.342,
  6: 3.447,
  7: 3.549,
  8: 3.646,
  9: 3.739},
 'Verified': {0: 5.56,
  1: 5.57,
  2: 5.56,
  3: 5.55,
  4: 5.53,
  5: 3.81,
  6: 3.92,
  7: 4.03,
  8: 4.14,
  9: 4.24}}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
df.set_index('Date_Time', inplace=True)


def do_bokeh_plot(df, idx):



    # Bokeh likes string for tooltips
    df['Date'] = df.index.astype(str) 

    p = figure(plot_width=1200,
               plot_height=800,
               x_axis_type="datetime",
               y_range=(1, 10),
               title="sample plot")


    col_list = ['Predicted', 'Verified'] #or df.columns
    color_list =['red', 'blue']

    for col, color in zip(col_list, color_list):

        source = df

        rend = p.line(x='Date_Time',
               y=col,
               source=source,
               legend_label=col,
               color=color,
               line_width=1.5)


        p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[rend],
                              tooltips=[("Value", "@{" + col + "}"),
                              ("Date_Time",  "@{Date}")],
                              mode='mouse'))


    p.legend.click_policy="hide"
    p.yaxis.axis_label='values'
    p.xaxis.axis_label='Date'

    # you might get a lot of plots in your browser with this
    #show(p)
    
    # save each plot with name as idx value from event_df
    output_file(idx.strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S') + ".html")

    

event_df_dict = {'Verified': {Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): 5.56,
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:06:00'): 5.57,
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:12:00'): 5.56,
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:18:00'): 5.55,
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:24:00'): 5.53,
  Timestamp('2020-12-31 23:30:00'): 3.81,
  Timestamp('2020-12-31 23:36:00'): 3.92,
  Timestamp('2020-12-31 23:42:00'): 4.03,
  Timestamp('2020-12-31 23:48:00'): 4.14,
  Timestamp('2020-12-31 23:54:00'): 4.24}}

event_df = pd.DataFrame(event_df_dict)


for idx in event_df.index:
    
    # use timedelta to select a slive of df from each event_df idx
    df_window = df.loc[(df.index > idx + pd.to_timedelta(-12, 'h')) & (df.index <= idx + pd.to_timedelta(12,'h'))]

    do_bokeh_plot(df_window, idx)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Bokeh!  Im finding pretty intuitive to use so far.  Is there any way to render plots at times given by my 'events.csv'  with +/-12 hour buffer?

Comment: I turned the plotting code into a function that can be called while iterating over the event_df index. It selects df rows 12 hours on either side of the index plots them, and saves to .html.

Comment: I had to make a change to the output_file to make it send the scripts to an appropriate path: output_file("/mydir/" + idx.strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S') + ".html")

It took a few runs to work but after restarting my kernel it seems to be working fine :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'd appreciate if you could mark this as the accepted answer, and up vote. Thanks!